# Updating the path 'files.$.updatedAt' would create a conflict at 'files.$

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using the following query:

```
editFileInformation: function(parentId, file, callback) {
    Parent.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            '_id': parentId,
            'files': {
                $elemMatch: {'_id': file._id}
            }
        },
        {$set: {'files.$': file}},
        callback
    );
},
```

I get the following error.

It works on models that doesn't have `updatedAt`, so it's related to that. But removing `updatedAt` from `file` doesn't fix it either.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Updating the path 'files.$.updatedAt' would create a conflict at 'files.$

Comment: Is that the complete error message?